# How can I manually serialize my POCO?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, serialization

I am using Silverlight with WCF.  I have a fairly complicated object that I am wanting to send to the server.  This object is shared among multiple services and so cannot be a data contract.  I am wondering if there is a simple way to do the serialization myself.  A way that works for both .Net 4 (server side) and Silverlight 4 (client side).

Note, I am not using RIA Services, because RIA Services has been a huge pain in my side since I started using it.

#### Edits:

I've attempted to use the `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute` to no avail.  I get the following exception from the service:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'

The reason seems evident.  I believe it is because the DLL that contains the POCO is a Silverlight Class Library.  This is the only way I know to share the object between both my WCF Service and my Silverlight Client.  The problem, I believe, is that the Silverlight DLL is using the Silverlight version of `System.Runtime.Serialization` and therefore the POCO cannot be used in a non Silverlight environment.  I have to share this POCO among multiple services so it has to exist in a separate Assembly.

This is why *I* want to control how I serialize my objects; serialize them inside the objects themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Json.NET. You can download the [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) which has support for .Net and Silverlight.

Serialize:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);
```

Deserialize:

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContractSerializer` supports POCO types both in Silverlight and in .NET 4.0. You can try it and it should just work.

*Update after edits*: You cannot reference a library built for Silverlight from .NET Framework, they reference different assemblies. You have a couple of options:

- Create two Class Library projects, one for SL and another for the full framework. Add the files in one of the projects, and on the other simply add links to them. This I've done many times and works fine.
- Create a Portable Library (PL) assembly. I haven't tried that, but that's exactly the goal of the PL - share assemblies between different .NET versions. You can try that to see if it works.

Comment: How though do I inform WCF that that is the way I want to serialize my POCOs?

Comment: Actually you can. You can reference a Silverlight class library from a .NET Framework assembly.  You just have to add the DLL itself rather than the project.  It is apparently very limiting though; if you have anything much more complex than a DTO, it gets buggered.

Comment: @Jordan, in theory this is possible, and I've tried that once. But this is not an supported scenario - it wasn't tested. So maybe it happens to work, but as you said, you may get unexpected errors during runtime (like the FileNotFoundException mentioned in the updated question), so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: There is no other way, as far as i know, to share entities among WCF services.  Which is bothersome because, one has to create one super-service for their entire organization or otherwise have a divided business layer.  Either options is miserable.  Am I wrong?

Comment: As I mentioned, portable libraries are supposed to deal exactly with this problem. There's already a second version of them, so I think they should work (it's just that I've never tried them)